# Align a main in the center of the screen (<body>)

Tags: html, css, grid, position

everytime I start a challenge on Frontend Mentor, one of the first things I want to do is center my main(element) on the screen. I have tried every possible way, but in the end only the horiozontal center works. I can not align my element verticaly. Following code must work in my opinion:

display: grid;
place-content: center;

but it doens't. When I create an "grid-container" and put elements inside all works well, it is just that I am missing something to center my main container on the screen.

Like I said, whenever I work inside a grid-container everything works fine, I followed a chapter in one of my son's courses and I know how it is supposed to work. But the very beginning, the centering in the body does not work

if possible I would like to work with a flex or grid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `display: flex;` or `display: grid;` on your `<body>` element is bad practice. If you end up deciding not to use `flex` or `grid` on your child elements your CSS will get very messy. Instead center the `<main>` like this:

```css
main {
  /*Center with this code*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
  /*Decorative*/
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  
  
}
```

```html
<main>Centered main</main>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it works. I have one more question though, when I put borders around all my elements I notice that the body is collapsed on top of the screen. Is this normal behavior ?

Comment: Can you please add a codepen link (codpen.io)

Comment: I think I found out what was missing: giving the child a dimension. When I added max-width, suddenly the code started working.